# Join on MAX value of one part of composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join

I'm trying to get a query to compare two tables by LEFT OUTER JOINing the two and finding any results that don't have a match in the right table. Problem is I have a composite key of TicketNo, ItemNo and UniqueID, and I need to only compare rows that have the highest UniqueID for any given TicketNo.

I need the data so my program knows whether it needs to update a Working copy table and what rows it needs to update if so.

Basically what I want is this:

```
SELECT TicketNo
FROM History t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Working t2 on 
max(t1.[UniqueID])=t2.[UniqueID] 
AND t1.[TicketNo]=t2.[TicketNo]
AND t1.[ItemNo]=t2.[ItemNo]
WHERE t2.[TicketNo] IS NULL
```

But I can't use the aggregate function max here. I don't know how I can use a subquery (or failing that a CTE, but I would prefer a subquery) to get only the max unique ID *for a given TicketNo*. I can't only join on the highest uniqueID in the table.

My data looks like this, assuming two duplicates:

```
TicketNo    UniqueID    ItemNo
15         1270662207   1
15         1184857061   1
```

In this case I only want the *first* row to return. I don't care if my Working table has the old rows with `TicketNo 15` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @History TABLE(UniqueID INT, TicketNo INT, ItemNo INT);
DECLARE @Working TABLE(UniqueID INT, TicketNo INT, ItemNo INT);

INSERT @History SELECT 15,1270662207,1
      UNION ALL SELECT 15,1184857061,1;

INSERT @Working SELECT 15,1184857061,1;

SELECT h.TicketNo, h.UniqueID
FROM 
(
    SELECT TicketNo, ItemNo, MAX(UniqueID) AS UniqueID
    FROM @History GROUP BY TicketNo, ItemNo
) AS h
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
@Working AS w
    ON h.TicketNo = w.TicketNo
    AND h.ItemNo = w.ItemNo
    AND h.UniqueID = w.UniqueID
WHERE w.TicketNo IS NULL;
```

Results:

```
TicketNo    UniqueID
----------- -----------
1270662207  15
```

Comment: heh, you didn't have to match it to my data. WOrks like a charm though.

Answer (score 2):

The technique to solve this is related to the groupwise max pattern.  In this case you're using it to find the full row that matches the max of an aggregated result in a different table instead of the same table.

But the idea is the same -- you'll have to use a derived table or a subquery to get the results.

Here's an example of the derived table method:

```
SELECT d.TicketNo FROM 
 (SELECT TicketNo, ItemNo, MAX(UniqueID) AS maxid FROM History t1 GROUP BY TicketNo, ItemNo) AS d 
 LEFT JOIN Working t2 ON d.TicketNo=t2.TicketNo AND d.ItemNo=t2.ItemNo AND d.maxid=t2.UniqueID 
WHERE t2.TicketNo IS NULL;
```

For more info see these links:

http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: A couple of minor issues with your query - (1) ambiguous column since your SELECT list does not have a table prefix (should be `d.TicketNo`) (b) multi-part identifier issue in `JOIN` clause - you alias `Working` as `t2` then your criteria specifies `t1` (one reason using meaningful aliases instead of t1, t2, t3 etc. makes sense). You also seem to be missing one of the join clauses (`ItemNo`).

Answer (score 0):

Try using GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses in this way :

```
SELECT TicketNo
FROM History t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Working t2 on 
t1.[UniqueID]=t2.[UniqueID] 
AND t1.[TicketNo]=t2.[TicketNo]
AND t1.[ItemNo]=t2.[ItemNo]
WHERE t2.[TicketNo] IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.[TicketNo], t1.[ItemNo]
ORDER BY t1.[UniqueID] DESC
```

Comment: Group by doesn't work without aggregating UniqueID. Plus I need a result set of only not matches, so I can't just sort the results, I need the results to not include non MAX UniqueIDs